# CPP Program adding 0 at the end of result

Tags: c++

I recently started picking up CPP, and today I tried making a program that would convert hours into
minutes, days or seconds, just to see if I was capable of doing so.

After working for about half an hour, after seeing no more errors in the output window, I tried debugging it and running it, and it all worked fine, but the result would always have an extra 0.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double hrs;
    char detr;

    cout << "Enter amount of hours: ";
    cin >> hrs;
    cout << "Convert to? \n";
    cout << "Minutes - a \n";
    cout << "Seconds - b \n";
    cout << "Days - c \n";
    cin >> detr;

    if (detr == 'a') {
        cout << hrs * 60;
    }
    else if (detr == 'b') {
        cout << hrs * 3600;
    }
    else
        (detr == 'c');
    {
        cout << hrs / 24;
    }
}
```

The code above, when compiled and tested, gives the result I expect, and then adds a zero on the end.

So I entered "1" for the "hrs" variable, and selected the "b" option, meaning it should multiply the hrs variable (1) by 3600 giving 3600, or 1 hour in seconds. But instead, it gives 36000.

I'm not desperate to get my time calculator working, I could just simply start multiplying the hours by 360 instead of 3600, but I see this as an opportunity to see what went wrong and try not to make the same mistake again.

I know this is probably a really basic and simple mistake but I just can't see it.

- Sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: The problem can be seen very easily if you used proper formatting. `else
        (detr == 'c');` should be `else if (detr == 'c')`

Comment: Actually, I don't see why the code in this question would think that `hrs / 24` is `0` if the user enters `1` for `hrs`. After all, `hrs` is a `double`, so the usual surprise of integer division occurring isn't relevant here. (Presumably another revision of the code has `int hrs;` instead of `double hrs;`?)

Comment: It returned 36000.0416667 here: [https://ideone.com/nIRnq0](https://ideone.com/nIRnq0)

Answer (score 5):

This unintentionally executes the cout line every time, printing `hrs/24`, i.e. `0`!

```
else (detr == 'c'); {
    cout << hrs / 24;
}
```

because it is parsed like this

```
else {
    detr == 'c';
}
{
    cout << hrs / 24;
}
```

It should just be

```
else {
    cout << hrs / 24;
}
```